# CakePHP 3.6 - Trigger en Event in a Shell/Command

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I need to do execute the same code in a Controller and in a Command (start a Calculation). So I thought to use an event for that, but I couldn't figure out how to trigger an Event in a Command.
Is it possible to do this or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution ...

```
$table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Calculations');
$eventManager = $table->getEventManager();

$event = new Event('Calculation.execute', $table, ['calculation' => $calculation]);
$eventManager->dispatch($event);
```

I used my TableClass to get the Eventmanger.

Comment: While this works it's not really a clean solution. You should read the events chapter in the official documentation. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html

Answer (score 0):

**Better way:**

```
<?php
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

// ...
$event = new Event('CustomEvent.example', null, ['Pass this', 'Data to event listener']);
$em = new EventManager();
$em->dispatch($event);
```